# A partir de dos arrays hacer una nueva pero con los numeros que no se repitan entre las dos arrays

Tags: java

El ejercicio trata de comparar dos arrays con numeros aleatorios. los numeros que salgan en una array pero en la otra no debe crearse una array con esos numero como se ve en ejemplo.

> Array 1: [5,7,9,2,9,8,3,2,4,8]
>
> Array 2: [6,2,5,8,3,0,5,9,2,0]
>
> Resultat:[7,4,6,0,0]

```
public class Exercici1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);
        int array1[] = new int[10];
        int array2[] = new int[10];
        int aux=0;
        boolean repetidos[] = new boolean[10];

        System.out.println("Array 1:");
        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            array1[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
            System.out.print(array1[i] + ",");

        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Array 2:");
        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            array2[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
            System.out.print(array2[i] + ",");

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
                if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                    repetidos[i] = true;
                    break;

                }else{
                    array1[i]=aux;
                }

            }

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
                if (array2[i] == array1[j]) {
                    repetidos[j] = true;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < repetidos.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(repetidos[i] + ",");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Segun tus ejemplos no termino de entender como haces los calculos.

Answer (score 0):

Hay que recorrer el array `a` preguntando si el valor existe en el array `b`, en el caso verdadero se agrega el valor al array `resultado`.

```
var a = [5,7,9,2,9,8,3,2,4,8];
var b = [6,2,5,8,3,0,5,9,2,0];
var resultado = [];

a.forEach(x =>{
    if(!b.includes(x)){
        resultado.push(x)
    }
});

b.forEach(x =>{
    if(!a.includes(x)){
        resultado.push(x)
    }
});
```

En el caso deba usarse unicamente arrays:

```
public void extract() {
    int[] a = randomIntArray(10);
    int[] b = randomIntArray(10);

    int[] resultado = compare(a, b, new int[] {});
    resultado = compare(b, a, resultado);

    for (int i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(resultado[i]);
    }
}

public int[] compare(int[] a, int[] b, int[] resultado) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        boolean match = false;
        for (int e = 0; e < b.length; e++) {
            if (a[i] == b[e]) {
                match = true;
            }
        }
        if (!match) {
            int[] temp = resultado;
            resultado = new int[temp.length + 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
                resultado[j] = temp[j];
            }
            resultado[temp.length] = a[i];
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}

public int[] randomIntArray(int lenght) {
    int[] array = new int[lenght];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = random(0, 9);
    }
    return array;
}

public int random(int min, int max) {
    return (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: No puedo usar la funcion forEach igualmente te lo agradezco

Comment: Haberlo dicho antes, bueno ahi tienes la solucion !

Comment: Los numeros son aleaterios se tienen que hacer con random , gracias.

Comment: Bueno fue entretenido, ahi lo tienes con el generador de numeros aleatorios. Suerte !

Comment: Acabo de ejecurarlo y veo que se repiten valores que estan en la array 1 y la array 2, igualmente gracias

Comment: jajaja, la verdad nose cual es el problema, tambien lo corri el programa y salio bien, aca un ejemplo: a = [0, 3, 8, 8, 4, 1, 6, 4, 6, 8], b = [5, 9, 0, 4, 5, 9, 0, 3, 3, 6], resultado = [8, 8, 1, 8, 5, 9, 5, 9]

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto: Busca en un array los que no están repetidos en el otro y viceversa, y los va añadiendo en un tercer array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
Random rand = new Random();
int array1[] = new int[10];
int array2[] = new int[10];
int repetidos[] = new int[20];
int repetido=0;
boolean rep=true;

System.out.println("Array 1:");
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    array1[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
    System.out.print(array1[i] + ",");

}
System.out.println();

System.out.println("Array 2:");
for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    array2[i] = rand.nextInt(10);
    System.out.print(array2[i] + ",");

}
System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    rep = false;
    for (int j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
            rep = true;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(rep==false) {
        repetidos[repetido] = array1[i];
        repetido++;
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    rep=true;
    for (int j = 0; j < array1.length; j++) {
        if (array2[i] == array1[j]) {
            rep = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(rep==false) {
        repetidos[repetido] = array2[i];
        repetido++;
    }
}

System.out.println();
for (int i = 0; i < repetidos.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(repetidos[i] + ",");

}
}
```

Comment: Lo he probado , no tengo que comprobar por posicion, sino toda la array es decir por ejemplo : [8,5,5,5] [9,5,5,5] el resultado seria [8,9,0,0,0]

Comment: Pablo, si deseas ayudar agrega una explicación de lo que realiza el código, revisar [answer].